# Can't find MSbuild tool in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, sonarqube

I have a SonarQube running with TFS 2013. Now i also have TFS 2015 installed in same build agent. When i try to connect SonarQube with TFS 2015 I am not able to find the MSBuildSonarQube Analysis Begin and MSBuildSonarQube Analysis End tool in build definition. I have a installed MSBuild latest version. How to install those plugin to connect to SonarQube to TFS 2015.
I am following documents founded on SonarQube.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+Team+Foundation+Server+2015+or+Visual+Studio+Team+Services
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+Team+Foundation+Server+2015+or+Visual+Studio+Team+Services

Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you install [TFS 2015 Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/tfs2015-update1-vs.aspx)?

Comment: What's the meaning of you have TFS 2015 installed in same build agent? Do you mean you want to use TFS 2015 + TFS 2013 Build Service? Are you using the old XAML build or the new build system based on tasks?

Comment: I am using old XAML build but now i want to move to the new build system so i updated TFS update 3.

Answer (score 0):

The documents you refer to is for TFS new build system. If you are already using the windows build agent, make sure you have upgraded your TFS2015 to Update1 or later.

If you haven't use windows build agent, you need to deploy a [Windows build agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/agents/windows) first.